# HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 504

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have an android application which I made with android studio and I use `KSOAP2` library to access a `WCFservice` which I made by myself too.
I'm facing a strange problem. I use the below code to create `HttpTransportSE` object and set `timeOut` on it:

```
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(my_url + my_service + "/",120000);
transport.setReadTimeout(120000);
```

I can call any methods of WCF service without any problem. But when I call a method that takes longer than 30 seconds, it fails and return the below error by `HttpTransportSE` object:

> HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 504

On my server side I set the `CommandTimeout` SqlCommand to 120 seconds. The stranger thing is that when I run the application on my real device with mobile data connection(No WiFi) I get the above error, But when I run it on the emulator of android studio (My PC have a WiFi connection) no error occurs and `HttpTransportSE` object returns the result in about 60 seconds successfully. I don't know what the problem is but i think my server and WCF service is correct because there is no error on the emulator. I guess there is a problem or some limitation in mobile data network.

Comment: HTTP 504 Error Code indicates a Gateway Timeout, that means that a Server while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not get a response in time from the upstream server that it needed in order to complete the request. - Are your Gateway and Proxy settings correct?

Comment: Test you link with `HttpClient`